# tee command not working as expected (with read and echo)

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Script and output is as below :

Script :

```
#!/bin/bash
#tee_with_read.sh
function tee_test()
{
    echo "***This should be printed first but it is not***"
    read -r -p "Enter input : "
    echo "You entered : $REPLY"
}
tee_test | tee -a logfile
```

Output :

```
$ ./tee_with_read.sh
Enter input : ***This should be printed first, but it is not***
"My Input"
You entered : "My Input"
```

I'm trying to append output to logfile.
But as you can see in ouput, it seems like first read gets excuted and then echo which is not as expected.

I'm using Git Bash  Version 3.1.23 on windows 10.
Since named pipe is not available in this version, I cannot use named pipe for logging purpose.

Comment: `read` displays its prompt on stderr. Your `echo` displays on stdout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`read -p` is writing it's output to `stderr` and `echo` is writing to `stdout`.  `stdout` is typically buffered while `stderr` is not, and so it's not uncommon to see `stderr` things show up before `stdout`.

You could have your `echo` also go to `stderr` if you like by doing `echo "string" >&2` or you could run it in the `unbuffer` command or similar tools if you have them available

Comment: I got it. So I could also write `echo "***This should be printed first, now it will***" ; echo -n "Enter Input : " ; read -r ; ` to get expected result.

Comment: Right, because then everything is going to `stdout` and will be ordered right on the stream (also, it's all then on `stdout` which is what `tee` will be expecting in your use case)

Comment: Or, just another alternate `tee_test 2>&1 | tee -a logfile` Thanks Renouf :)